# Android Contacts: Is it possible to reference a given contact entry using a URN?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts

Let me try and clarify my intentions.

I'm developing an app that accesses to the Android contacts provider. I have already implemented a mechanism for pulling contacts from the contacts provider and storing the results in an SQLite table. Currently, when I query for the results of a contact's _ID, I can retrieve all the data for that contact, phone numbers, email addresses, etc.

However, in order to specify which of those my app should use on future occasions, I have to store the resulting contact data (e.g. CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE etc) in the SQL table.

This presents a problem if the data in the Android contacts provider has changed. One solution I have considered is to re-query the _ID and store the data that has changed. However, implementing such a solution requires gathering all data for that contact, making it difficult to determine the correct contact data to use.

My question is thus:

Is there a unique record key used in the Android Provider's contact data, in the same way as there is in the Provider's contact entry itself? A phone number or email address equivalent of Contact._ID?

Failing that, does the Android contacts provider store the last modified date and time? I'm hoping that if I can't reference the contact data in the provider, I can at least run a check to see if anything has changed since the contact was selected for use in the app, allowing my app to alert the user that the data has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoi may use ContentObserver with the help of a service to monitor for contacts change or update.

for example-

extend contentObserver-

```
public class Contact_change extends ContentObserver
```

register contentobserver-

```
Contact_change changeObserver = new Contact_change();
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,chageobserver);
```

By using this you can monitor for contact changes and update your database.

Comment: Thanks for the update suggestion. I'll adapt it to my code and give it some testing ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

So while looking to see what was possible, I've come across some interesting findings by doing a localised record dump to my tablet.

I incorrectly referred to the phone _ID when asking my question. It's there, but it references individual records in any given contact. This might be useful, it might be exactly what I hoped, but it might also be a dead end.

So far, I've retrieved a contact using the Android Contacts Provider, which returns the contact's data including the fields that follow

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
```

After assigning the _ID to a String and using it in a query, I initially searched for the _ID in the ContactsContract.Data._ID field, which did not work as intended.

That's when I realised I was doing it wrong. I needed to apply the search to ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, which then retrieved all related data records for my selected contact.

Having corrected the error and re-ran my query, I found a series of records for the CONTACT_ID, each of which had its' own unique _ID (with the exception of photos and binary data, which all had a null reference to _ID instead.

Now the question is: Does this data reference change even if a phone number, email address or IM entry is modified, as opposed to deleted and re-created? I'll probably find out through further testing, but I wanted to ask if anyone had already tried this first.

Ultimately, I am hoping my internal SQL table can store only the CONTACT_ID and the _ID for each entry, relying on callbacks to the Android Provider to pull the relevant values. That way, I can be sure the data displayed in my app is up to date between the app and the stored contact data on the device.

Combined with the change notifier code provided here, I should be able to alert the user to any changes that may require action on their part.

Update:

More investigation reveals that the UID associated with a given contact entry is preserved through entry edits.

The UID is lost obviously on deletion, and in my brief testing, I have not found UID's being recycled. This solves a referential integrity issue for me at least, as that UID won't suddenly reference another record out of nowhere.

The upshot for anyone else wanting to reference individual entries in the Contacts Provider is that it's possible, and you can store only the _ID and still retrieve individual entries in the provider.